# My project running on the game screen is crushed when the app 'build and run' on real phone?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can run the project in Unity (game screen), but the application crush when I try to do build and run on the phone.

I'm using `unity` 2019.1.0f2 last version. Build setting screen is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSPwg.jpg

And logcat:

> 04-16 11:23:42.430  1429  8394 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.dalistoadsoft.cubecrash/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (has extras)} from uid 10012
>   04-16 11:23:42.445  1429  8394 D ActivityManager: [MemInfo] Process does not exist before starting ActivityRecord{82fae27 u0 com.dalistoadsoft.cubecrash/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t2174}. System free memory=1260134400
>   04-16 11:23:42.456  1429  8394 I ActivityManager: Start proc 20035:com.dalistoadsoft.cubecrash/u0a249 for activity com.dalistoadsoft.cubecrash/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity duration: 11
>   04-16 11:23:42.457  1429  8394 D ActivityManager: [MemInfo] Process does not exist before starting ActivityRecord{82fae27 u0 com.dalistoadsoft.cubecrash/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t2174}. System free memory=1258782720
>   04-16 11:23:42.480  1429  1666 I ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {0 0.85 286mcc3mnc [tr_TR,en_US] ldltr sw423dp w752dp h399dp 408dpi nrml long land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1080) s.41}
>   04-16 11:23:42.492  1429  1666 I ActivityManager: Override config changes=480 {0 0.85 286mcc3mnc [tr_TR,en_US] ldltr sw423dp w752dp h399dp 408dpi nrml long land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1080) s.41} for displayId=0
>   04-16 11:23:42.801  1429  9278 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.dalistoadsoft.cubecrash/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
>   04-16 11:23:42.821  1429  1516 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.dalistoadsoft.cubecrash u0

Comment: sometimes, some external libraries can cause similar problems like, facebook api..
do you use any external api or library?

Comment: The same error persists even though I delete external libraries in the project.